# Simple Python-Connector program - MySQL error

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to use connector python for inserting records into MySQL

I'm unable to understand why i'm getting

> ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'list'
>   cannot be converted to a MySQL type

This is my simple program

```
import mysql.connector

 #All variables like user_name etc. are initialized


cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='password',database='consumer')
curA = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)

insert_query = "INSERT INTO sno_social_listener( user_name, user_profile_url, message_url, message_title, message_content, created_on ) VALUES ('%s',  '%s',  '%s',  '%s',  '%s',  '%s')"

curA.execute(insert_query,(user_name, user_profile_url,complaint_source_url, message_title, message_content,created_on))
```

Comment: Can you add a `print (user_name, user_profile_url,complaint_source_url, message_title, message_content,created_on)`

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
curA.execute(insert_query %(user_name, user_profile_url,complaint_source_url, message_title, message_content,created_on))
```

Also at end

```
cnx.commit()
```